# How to find a word in a dictionary based on simple constraints?

Tags: regex, string, search, dictionary

I'd like to be able to get all the words in a dictionary (text file) that match a quite simple constraint.

Here are a few examples of what I'm trying to achieve:

- For string "abcd", look for all the words beginning with "a" and containing "b", "c" and "d" at least one time
- For string "bccd", look for all the words beginning with "b" and containing at least two "c" and at least one "d" ("bydcuc" and "bicdzcd" are valid words)

The first letter in the string is always the one that should begin the words, and the following letters should be contained **at least** the number of times they appear in the string.

For example, string "bra" could return "barbara", as could string "baar" or "baraa".

My first idea was to use a regex but I didn't manage to say that the letters could be found in any order. I don't want to build a regex using permutations.

My second idea was to loop through all the words beginning with my first letter. For each of those words, I would check if they contain the right letters. But as I'd like to be efficient, this doesn't seem very acceptable.

Do you have any idea of how I could achieve that in a nice and efficient way?

I'm used to python but I'm open to any other suggestion for this purpose. (Maybe a database rather than a txt file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NOTE]: I will be using the word `list` since I am python oriented however it can be `list`, `array`, `ArrayList`, whatever...

## First Test

Narrow it down one by one. Start with a list of all the words in the text file.
Run the first test which is starts with `some_char` and then create a new list that contains all the words that match the first condition. For this one you can get the first character from the input string and then use `regex` on that to match all words as follows: (probably by using a loop to test each word and add it to a new list if it fits the condition)

I'll be using the example of 'abbbc'

`'^a.*'`

## Second Test

Then, you can run your second test as follows:

> 1) Get the second character (index of 1), in my case it is 'b' and count the number of times it occurs in the string, in my case it is `3`.
>
> 2) For each word in your narrowed list, count the number of times the specific character occurs ('b' for me) and if it is greater than or equal to `3` (or whatever the count was in the original string), add it to a new list.

## Third Test

Repeat the second test as many times as necessary for each character in the original string ('abbbc'), each time narrowing down the list of words permitted by these criteria.

## Result

By the end, you should have a list of the words that meet your requirements.

## [Note]

I know that it seems lengthy but it should be relatively easy to program.

Good Luck. Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. That's exactly what I was thinking about in my second idea (though I would have done a foreach on the letters in the pattern rather than a foreach on the letters in the words). But with a very big dictionary, I'm afraid it would take too much memory to load the full list of words. Do you think it would be OK with a 100MB file?

Comment: @mimipc, I suggest you split up your file into `dict1.txt`, `dict2.txt`, `dict3.txt`, ... into a few files. Also, I think the smaller chunks would fit the RAM better.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to split it by first letter (a.txt, b.txt, ...)

Comment: @mimipc, That is actually a great idea! That way, you would only have to load `1/26th`~ish of the whole dictionary!

Comment: A bit like nginx's cache system, I also thought about making a directory tree by first and second letter for large dictionaries (/a/a.txt, /a/b.txt) but this may be difficult to use the way I want

Comment: @mimipc, Potentially, and after a while, it becomes overkill. Also, you said order doesn't matter. So `'ab'` would actually match `'acb'` but since you would only be looking in `/a/b.txt`, you would never find it. Previous suggestion better way to go

Comment: @mimipc, If my answer was helpful would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Comment: I'll try this in python and see if it's fast enough :)

Comment: @mimipc, Oh perfect, you're using python. So you understood my references to `list` and what not. :P